# Cakephp and setup fault notices

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two warnings related to cakephp security

> Please change the value of 'Security.salt' in app/Config/core.php to
>   a salt value specific to your application
>   [CORE\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php, line 717]
>
> Please change the value of 'Security.cipherSeed' in
>   app/Config/core.php to a numeric (digits only) seed value specific to
>   your application [CORE\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php, line 721]

But I have no idea of what that actually means. Is it just alright to leave them as they are even in really large and important applications ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, reading those two messages, I would say you must edit the `app/Config/core.php` file, to put values that are specific to you / your application, and cannot be guessed, for the two `Security.salt` and `Security.cipherSeed` configuration entries.

Considering the names of those properties, using specific values *(unique to your application, and not common to all Cakephp applications in the world)* is probably better for security.

And, answering your *"is it alright to leave them as they are ?"* question : if you get security-related warnings, do you really think it's OK to just ignore them ?

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I ignore them because I guess those two aren't the essential keys to protect any applications.

Comment: Even if not the two most essential keys to security, the fact that the developpers of the framework wrote some code to check the values of those entries, and raise warnings if they are not OK, should indicate that something is wrong there... and I should add that just ignoring warnings is generally not something one should do.

Comment: I accept your reply, but I am not really satisfied, I know nothing about how important they both actually are from your posts.

Comment: The first one is used to generate hashes (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29 ) ; and the second is used as a seed for encryption (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed )